# Having trouble customizing the paragraph using titlesec in Overleaf (LaTex)

Tags: titlesec, overleaf, sections-paragraphs

I am working on customizing sections, subsections, and paragraphs for my report.

I almost have the functionality that I want, but I am missing a small part.

Current Situation:

```
\titleformat{\paragraph}
[runin]
{\large\mdseries\sffamily}
{\rlap{\color{paragraphColor}\rule[-6pt]{\textwidth}{1.2pt}}}
{15pt}
{\color{paragraphColor}#1}
```

The code above gives the following result of the colorized paragraph heading:

[image]

I can also underline the paragraph by doing this:

```
\titleformat{\paragraph}
[runin]
{\large\mdseries\sffamily}
{\rlap{\color{paragraphColor}\rule[-6pt]{\textwidth}{1.2pt}}}
{15pt}
{\uline{#1}}
```

Which gives the following result:

[image]

**Desired Result**:
I am trying to combine those two by making the paragraph both colored and underlined.

The closest I was able to get to is this:

```
\titleformat{\paragraph}
[runin]
{\large\mdseries\sffamily}
{\rlap{\color{paragraphColor}\rule[-6pt]{\textwidth}{1.2pt}}}
{15pt}
{\uline{\color{paragraphColor}#1}}
```

Unfortunately, this only colors the first word:

[image]

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}  % Add explicit option !
\usepackage{ulem} % For \uline
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{paragraphColor}{RGB}{190, 30, 30}

\titleformat{\paragraph}
    {\large\mdseries\sffamily\color{paragraphColor}}
    {\thesubsection}
    {1em} 
    {\uline{#1}
}

\begin{document}
    \paragraph{Test paragraph}
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Remember tu add `explicit` option to `titlesec`. More info [here](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf) (*3.7. Other Package Option*)

If you want to add `[runin]` for having all in the same line after the paragraph, try with this:

```
\titleformat{\paragraph}
    [runin]
    {\large\mdseries\sffamily}
    {\thesubsection}
    {1em} 
    {\color{paragraphColor}\uline{#1}
}
```

[image: result2]

Comment: That works, thanks a lot!